# Return Access Denied View

Tags: angularjs, spring-security

I'm trying return view permission denied from Spring to html view with angularjs.

Spring Controller

```
@RequestMapping("accessDenied")
public String getAccessDeniedPage() {
    log.info("accessDeniedPage");
    return "auth/accessDenied";
}
```

Angular Controller

```
$routeProvider.when('/accessDenied', {
    title: 'Access Denied',
    templateUrl: 'auth/accessDenied',
});
```

When I change view to view which I haven't permission, view doesn't change. Only in the log (chrome):

> GET http://localhost:8080/users/layout 403 (Forbidden)

How Can I return in this case accedDenied.html?

BTW How Can I return Validate Error Message from Spring (EntityClass) to angular?

Comment: Can use `$routeChangeError` event but you need to be able to send user to something that will render. Logic doesn't make sense with what you are currently doing

Comment: Like @charlietfl , you can use `$routeChangeError` , and you can just use a `resolve` in your routeProvider function to check its validity. Then you can throw your errors in `.run()`